# crash on a vector of vector only after a clear

Tags: c++, string, vector, crash

I've a problem with this code: it crashes always but when I comment: dataResults[i].clear();

Any idea about the reason?

```
std::vector<std::string> r_OCRtoRetrieve;
std::vector<std::string> DBentries;

//stuff..

int distance = 9999; //TODO change here
int minDistance = 9999;

for(int i=0; i< r_OCRtoRetrieve.size(); i++)
    for(int j=0; j< DBentries.size(); j++)
    {
        distance = calcDistance( (const char *)r_OCRtoRetrieve[i].c_str(),(const char *) DBentries[j].c_str());

        if (distance == minDistance)
            dataResults[i].push_back(DBentries[j]);
        else
            if(distance < minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = distance;
                dataResults[i].clear();
                dataResults[i].push_back(DBentries[j]);
            }

    }
```

Edit:

Found the error.. I had to initialize it.. here it is the code:

```
  for(int i=0; i< r_OCRtoRetrieve.size(); i++)
  {
    dataResults.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());

    for(int j=0; j< DBentries.size(); j++)
    {
      distance = calcDistance( (const char *)r_OCRtoRetrieve[i].c_str(),(const char *) DBentries[j].c_str());

      if (distance == minDistance)
    dataResults[i].push_back(DBentries[j]);
      else
    if(distance < minDistance)
    {
      minDistance = distance;
      if(dataResults[i].size() > 0)
        dataResults[i].clear();

      dataResults[i].push_back(DBentries[j]);
    }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Could you give us the exception message ?

Comment: What is your varlable `dataResults` defined as?

Comment: what is dataResults? I don't see the declaration.

Comment: Why the redundant casts in the call to `calcDistance`?

Comment: More importantly, what is `dataResults`, where is it declared, how is data inserted into it elsewhere, and are you sure that it has `i` elements when you access `dataResults[i]`?

Comment: the definition is:  std::vector < std::vector<std::string> > dataResults;

Comment: I'm sure it has i elements, if I erase that line it doesn't crash anymore

Comment: @manty `c_str()` returns a `const char*`. So yes, the casts *are* redundant.

Comment: @manty: Post a minimal, compilable example and it will be easier to help you :)

Comment: Have you checked `if (dataResults.size()>i) dataResults[i].clear();`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an *index out of range* exception it's probably because your index `i` is out of range of the vector `dataResults`

If that wasn't obvious enough basically if `i` is greater than `dataResults.size()` then `dataResults[i].clear();` will throw an exception.

Edit:

Consider replacing your index based loops with STL iterators and replacing your c-style casting with C++ style casting.  Your if statement could be revisited as well ...

Edit 2:

Was a guessing at a likely problem as you didn't tell us what the exception was but you have a `vector<vector<string>>` right?  If so you need to check what you are indexing into  a valid position before calling methods or construct your loop so that it will not index out of bounds.

Something like so:

```
if (dataResults.size() > i)
{
   // now we know dataResults[i] will be valid
   dataResults[i].clear();
   // etc
}
```

Honestly I'd probably do something more along the lines of this:

```
    typedef std::vector<std::string> StrArray;
    for(StrArray::const_iterator ret(r_OCRtoRetrieve.begin()); ret != r_OCRtoRetrieve.end(); ++ret)
    {
        // ret will be an const iterator to each string element in r_OCRtoRetrieve
        for(StrArray::const_iterator entry(DBentries.begin()); entry != DBentries.end(); ++entry)
        {
            // entry will be an const iterator to each string element in DBentries
            distance = calcDistance(ret->c_str(), entry->c_str());

            // init new StrArray in dataResults as needed
            // set new min distances as needed
            // push back strings to dataResults
            // whatever else you want to do
            // yata yata
        }
}
```

Comment: thats a great explanation but it doesn't make sense since poster said the error goes away if the line is commented out. The very next line also indexes dataResults[i] which would throw the very same exception.

Comment: more accurately, you will get undefined behaviour

Comment: I'm going to catch the exception because there isn't any message.. just a crash

Comment: "greater than datResults.size()", to be nitpicky it should be greater than or equal to

Comment: I added:  if(dataResults.size() > 0)
   dataResults[i].clear(); but same problem

Comment: uhm but I don't think the casts are linked to my problem

Comment: Edited. The casts weren't part of the problem just unnecessary as `c_str()` returns a `const char*` already. I believe you may have been just checking against the wrong vector or wrong index.

Answer (score 1):

probably, the size of your vector `dataResults` is smaller than a certain value of `i`

Answer (score 0):

What is in DataResults when you start?  Anything?  If not, then then the first time through, when distance is anything less than 9999 then the code will attempt to clear a nonexistent location at the first, zeroth index and complain.

If you do a debug build, you should get a meaningful message.

Comment: when I start I have just std::vector < std::vector<std::string> > dataResults;  uhm your explanation makes really sense... I'm going to check

Comment: unfortunately I can't do it now. I tried to put try and catch but no ouput

Comment: Do you mean if(dataResults.size() > 0) ?